# HDRi not showing up in render, evee or cycles

Tags: rendering, hdri

[image]HDRi not showing up in render, evee or cycles. I've done this a thousand times but for some reason no luck, 2.91 and 2.92. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To make the HDRI work properly you would have to use an [Environment Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/environment.html) node and you are currently using an *Image Texture* node, just swap them out:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much I just figured that out and it worked but drove me nuts! Have a great weekend!!

Comment: If that "worked", please consider to accept the answer @Saberblend see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers